# Black screen after installing Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04

## The Issue

I recently updated from 18.04 (with running nvidia drivers) to 20.04.
Now, after installing the nvidia drivers I get a black screen after selecting Ubuntu in the GRUB menu. At the top of the screen it is written in console style

```
/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 1479251/17219584 files, 57208401/68869632 blocks
```

## What I tried

I tried different versions of installation like

- `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`
- `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`
- using the Software&Updates -> Additional Drivers GUI
- launch Ubuntu from bootable USB and try boot-repair

All resulted in the same behaviour / didn't help.

To revert the changes I can do Ctrl+Shift+F6 which gives me a prompt, login with username and passwort and do

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
sudo apt autoremove
reboot
```

which gives me a proper login screen again - without nvidia drivers obviously.

## My System

`ubuntu-drivers devices` yields

```
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (XPS 15 9550)
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I run Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10 dual boot.

Answer (score 2):

## Sort of a Solution

Rather than relying on the system which I got from doing an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I did a complete fresh re-install of Ubuntu 20.04 and now everything seems to work. I did update the drivers via "Software&Updates" in the Additional Drivers tab.